# WPF TextBlock value is not updating with bound variable

Tags: c#, wpf

I have bound a variable in `WPF` with a `TextBlock`. Everything was working fine. Here is the relevant code for this :

```
 <TextBlock  Text="{Binding LblContent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
```

I set the value of `LblContent` when applications starts.

```
 LblContent= string.Format("{0}", common.ProjectTeam);
```

It is working on my physical machine in windows 7.

[image: original windows 7 snapshot]

But when I run the same program on Virtual Machine having windows 7 the value of `LblContent` is not updated.

[image: virtual windows 7 snapshot]

I checked the same thing on Windows 8. And it is working correctly in both - physical and virtual machines.

Why the value of bound variable is not get updated in virtual machine?

Comment: Most likely because either there's something else going on in your code that you're not showing, or they're not the same executables.

Comment: if your `common.ProjectTeam` is from a Database it could be you are not connected

Comment: The problem is same thing is working on windows 8 but is not working correctly in windows 7. There are other fields too whose value I am fetching from database. So Connectivity is not the issue. Problem is something else.@WiiMaxx

Comment: The supplied code is not sufficient to diagnose the cause of the problem. You mention that `LblContent` is assigned on application start which would mean there would be no "update" of the bound variable, it would just use the value  assigned during application start when the view is rendered. I can only guess there is more to it. Please provide the class/property definition of `LblContent` and the place where it gets assigned.

Comment: Sounds like you are getting an exception from some other difference before reaching this code. If you can run Visual Studio on a working and none working pc do so and view the Output window.  If not, capture and log the UnhandledException event in the App class. (Which you should be doing any way.)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of this problem.

Value of textblock was not updating in vmware of windows 7. When i replace textblock with Label, its working fine.